# Apex buttons in Interactive Reports break when built-in search filter used

Tags: oracle-apex-5

In Apex 5.0.2. I have created a copy-to-clipboard function in my interactive report. The user can copy the value of a hidden column by clicking on this button that is set in a column and is repeating in every row (see image below).

[image]

The copy column is edited with an HTML Expression which does the following:

```
<button class="copytoclipboard 
           t-Button 
           t-Button--noLabel 
           t-Button--icon
           t-Button--stretch" customid="#COPY#" type="button">
    <span class="t-Icon fa fa-copy" aria-hidden="true">
 </span>
</button>
```

My Dynamic Action with the event 'click', jQuery selector .copytoclipboard has 2 true actions. 1 sets the value of a page item (text_field) by getting the customid from that row with:

```
this.triggeringElement.getAttribute("customid")
```

The second one then copies this value to the clipboard.

This works fine and when I inspect the button element, I see the correct HTML output, with the correct value. However, as soon as I use the built-in search filter in the Interactive Report, my button breaks and clicking this button does not trigger my dynamic actions anymore, however, inspecting the element still returns the expected HTML output.

Can somebody please clarify why this is happening, and how this could be avoided?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I had to put the Event Scope of the Dynamic Action to Dynamic, which is set to Static by default. Using the built-in page filter does a PPR of the report, thus when static, the event handler is longer bound to the triggering element.

> Static (default) - Binds the event handler to the triggering elements
>   for the lifetime of the current page, but will no longer be bound if
>   the triggering elements are updated via Partial Page Refresh (PPR).
>
> Dynamic - Binds the event handler to the triggering elements for the
>   lifetime of the current page, including any triggering elements that
>   are recreated via Partial Page Refresh (PPR).
>
> Once - Binds the event
>   handler to the triggering elements for a once only event.